# AppStore submission fails saying Missing Info.plist value - 'CFBundleIconName', even after having it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, app-store

I'm trying to push my app to TestFlight. Once it's uploaded, within couple of minutes I get the rejection mail saying

> Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key
> 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle

But my app contains AppIcon in assets folder, info.plist and target.

[image]

[image]

I see other stackoverflow question (Xcode 9, iOS 11) where the answers suggest to add the AppIcon in info.plist file, but I feel this case is different as this is a newly created SwiftUI app which already has those values.

Comment: Do you have an extension? Maybe the issue is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the Asset folder was inside another folder called **preview content**.

Moving the Asset folder from that child to the root folder fixed this issue.

Also don't forget to delete the duplicate copies of the Assets folder. These duplicates won't be shown in Xcode, but you can view them through Finder app in MAC.

While debugging check if the **.ipa** file contains the assets folder or AppIcon.